# Creating a submit button on a registration form in Microsoft Access 

Tags: ms-access

I dont have much Access experience. I'm an intern at a database management company and my boss gave me a test project. He wants me to create a registration form with a submit button to enter some data into a table. I created the form, but how do I create a submit button that enters data into the table?

Comment: Alright - do you know what is meant by such terms as 'Unbound Form' and have a decent understanding of the SQL language?

Comment: Why do you think it needs to be done this way? You might very well find that a bound form with the Data Entry property turned on will do exactly what you need with almost no code at all.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using straight Microsoft Access - you could base a form on the table (I know, not a terribly great idea for those in the know - just keeping it simple), and as you enter information into the form, it enters it into each respective column of the record - no submission action necessary, when you reach the end of the record - the next new record with blank columns is given to you automatically for filling in.

Now, if you -really- need a form that works like they do on the internet - you'd have to create an unbound form - then create a 'Submit' button with VBA code that takes the text boxes you have on the form and inserts them into the table in your database, clearing your fields after submission to allow for the entry of your next record.  You can even write up a 'Cancel' button that clears all of your fields to start again if you so desire.

I am sorry if I am being very general - but you haven't given us a lot to go on.

Comment: that answer is the one i wanted and what i am trying to do...i just dont have experience with vba...im learning

Comment: Why do you think you need an unbound form? That's exactly the opposite of the way Access is designed -- it leverages the benefits of bound data to make a whole boatload of tasks much easier than they are with unbound forms. The HTML form mode is a step backwards from what Access provides by default.

Comment: The original questioner worded it as "wants me to create a registration form with a submit button to enter data into table" which I took to mean he had a specific design requirement needing just such a method.  I know, it's easier to have bound forms - hence my "Now, if you -really- need a form that works like they do on the internet..." part.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said the way to go here is an unbound form. Here is a generic code template I use when connecting to a JET database. Note the use of DAO over ADO as DAO is faster when talking to a JET data source

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set db = DBEngine(0).OpenDatabase(strLinked_db_path)
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("tblHours_lost", dbOpenTable)

With rst
     .Addnew
        !Hours_Lost = Me.txtHours_lost
        !Type = Me.cboLoss_type
        !do_not_deduct = Me.chkDo_not_deduct
        !Notes = Me.txtNotes
        !Start_time = Me.txtStart_time    
    .Update
End With

rst.Close
db.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

All you need to do is open the recordset and put the data in, its quite simple to do once you get the hang of it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make a string date should be saved.

Microsoft access is designed to add in the properties from your form a table and then you can add a field and you don't have to make a `Submit` button the state should be saved, all strings will be done automatically by the system.

Answer (score -1):

U need to create connection string which will provide path to to date
then create a command object then give the con object as parameter to command object along with command and execute it

Comment: can you be a little more specific...keep in mind i am a beginner at this